# Setting up bPupup

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, bpopup

I'm currently trying to get bPopup (http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/) to work on my page.
I've found this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/) which shows to get the script to work. Using following code:
    ;(function($) {

```
     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

But i want to get a little more fancy. 
On this page (http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) is several customization elements described. The problem is that i can't write javascripts and jQuery so i have no clue of how to i.e. add a transition to the script.

Hope somebody can guide me.

Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to write anything.

See the transition effect you want and so change this line:

```
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
```

To (for instance):

```
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    speed: 650,
    transition: 'slideIn',
    transitionClose: 'slideBack'
});
```

You need only to include the two libraries:

- jQuery: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
- bpopup: https://rawgit.com/dinbror/bpopup/master/jquery.bpopup.min.js

A simple snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  // Binding a click event
  // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
  $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
    e.preventDefault();

    // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            speed: 650,
            transition: 'slideIn',
     transitionClose: 'slideBack'
    });

  });

});
```

```css
#element_to_pop_up { 
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:15px;
  color:#000;
  display:none; 
  padding:20px;
  min-width:400px;
  min-height: 180px;
}
.bClose{
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dinbror/bpopup/master/jquery.bpopup.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
<button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <a class="bClose">x<a/>
    Content of popup
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#element_to_pop_up { 
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none; 
    padding:20px;
    min-width:400px;
    min-height: 180px;

    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #999;
}
.bClose{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:5px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
box-shadow: none;
font: bold 131% sans-serif;
padding: 0 6px 2px;
position: absolute;
right: -7px;
top: -7px;
background-color: #2b91af;
}
```